# Chrome forgets my saved passwords when I close the application

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

All the other QA's I've found tell people how to get Chrome to remember their passwords. That is not my issue. My issue is that Chrome happily remembers passwords for all the sites I want it to, except once I exit Chrome entirely, when I re-launch it later, it has **forgotten them all**.

Comment: Which operating system? Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: Does it remember ANY settings?  If not, then likely the DB file that contains the settings is not in a writable location, or else a patch is installed to reset settings on startup.

Comment: I'm on OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8, I have the following extensions installed: Bit.ly, ReadLater, Evernote.

Comment: It seems to remember everything else (bookmarks, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

If it is a UNIX/Linux OS, you can run Chrome under `strace` (or `truss` or `dtrace` etc) to find any files it fails to read/write on startup/shutdown. You can use `-e trace=file` with `strace` to trace specifically file I/O related syscalls. See [strace manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) for details.

There is a variety of reasons it could fail to read from or to write to a file e.g. wrong pathname, incorrect permissions, quota exceeded etc.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I have Chrome installed on both my Mac Pro and Macbook Pro. On my Mac Pro, I had Chrome configured to save passwords. However, on my Macbook Pro, I had it configured to **not** save passwords! This prevents saved passwords from being remembered after Chrome is exited each time on my Mac Pro.

Comment: Did the problem present, for you, even if you didn't access the MacbookPro when you exited chrome on the MacPro? (I have the same problem as you (google forgets pws), but I use Chrome on two Ubuntu laptops and one Linux Mint.)